# How to show that the integral of this volume-form over $S^n$ isn't 0?

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, differential-forms, volume, exterior-algebra

Let $S^n$ be the n-dimensional unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$.

Let $\omega$ be the volume form that's defined for all $p\in M$ by $\omega_{\vec{p}} = x^1\wedge...\wedge x^n$ s.t. $x^1,...,x^n$ is the dual basis for some orthonormal directed basis $x_1,...,x_n$ of $T_{\vec{p}}(M)$ .

I would like to show that $\int_{S^n}\omega \neq 0$.

To the best of my understanding, not only does $\int_{S^n}\omega \neq 0$, but $\int_{S^n}\omega = Vol(S^n)$; However, I don't know how to prove neither claim.

Comment: Since $x_i$ (or $x^i$) are used as coordinates, it's a very bad habit to use $x_i$ for a basis for the tangent plane and $x^i$ for the dual basis. Break this habit immediately. Indeed, can you write down this volume form explicitly using the usual embedding of $S^n$ in $\Bbb R^{n+1}$? Start with $n=1$ and $n=2$.

Comment: thanks a bunch for your guidance. i would love to hear about some healthier notations - could you please tell me what are the proper notations used for such objects? as for the guidance you provided, i will try to work in the suggested direction. thank you :) edit - what does 'the usual embedding' mean? please excuse my ignorance.

Comment: You might wanna ask yourself why your $\omega$ is well-defined. Does it depend on the basis?

Comment: it does not. if the we look at the wedges of the duals of B1 and B2, the wedge of the basis dual to B1 is equal to that of B2 times the determinant of the transition matrix from B1 to B2. since both are orthonormal, said det is +-1, and since they're both positively oriented, said det is 1, and the wedges are equal. how do i use that to calculate the integral of the form on the manifold?

Comment: @orangefruits the usual notation would be $\partial_{x_i}$ or similar for elements of $T_pM$, and $dx_i$ for it's dual.

Comment: thank you! @doetoe